# how to create ts (transport stream) video file from mp4 in android

Tags: android, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, mp4parser, jcodec

In my project I need to implement an HLS (HTTP live Streaming) for an android device and it stream to an iOS device to play where android device will record the video and send it to server and iOS device will play the stream from the server using an m3u8 file. In the link below
[Click Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html)
They have mention "Currently, the supported delivery format is MPEG-2 Transport Streams for audio-video".

Now problem is that in android you can record only in mp4 by default (correct me if i am wrong). Now I need some third party API or library like ffmpeg, Gstreamer, Xuggler, Jcodec to transcode recorded mp4 to ts files.

ffmpeg, jffmpeg and Gstreamer have a learning curve and to setup time and also need NDK. So I need some help because I don't have enough time to try one of these please refer me if you know any library which is easy to use and does not have a complex learning and setup time. Like Jcodec which is pure java base and plug and play type library but I don't think it can do this for me as they have mention in there documentation they support h262 codec support yet but i need h264 and ACC for audio.

Comment: jcodec is horribly slow

Answer (score 0):

FYI:
JJPMEG

It is a Java binding to FFmpeg and it have an android verison too. Maybe you can give it a try.

https://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/

Or:

Maybe you can just record the video with supporting encoding and transcode the video in the server side?

Comment: I can't use a server side solution as server guy told me what ever I have to do it is on mobile side.